# Polygons from PostGIS table won't highligt in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.2

QGIS 2.14.1 / PostGIS 2.2.1

I have a table with polygons and a view on this table in PostGIS. When I select the features from the view in QGIS with Identify Features, the objects highlight on the map.

When I identify the same features from the table they won't highlight.

The table has a primary key, the view doesn't.

The table was created with FME and the view was created by hand in SQL.

I don't know how highlighting works under the hood but my best guess is a select statement. Probably based on OIDs. The table doesn't have OIDs. Enable OIDs in PgAdmin didn't solve the problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared with rebuilding the layer style. As we save default styles in PostGIS, I suspect it had something to do with building the style with an earlier version of QGIS but I can't reproduce the problem.